# Convert mysql count(*) to int in bash?

Tags: bash, mysql

I'd like to execute this and check if count is 0, 1 or > 1 in bash.

```
mysql -e "select count(*) from mydb.mydb;"
```

The output is:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

I don't know how to parse this. Also this will be used in a cron job, so I can't have any output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could suppress the tab column name by:

```
ROW_CNT=$(mysql --raw --batch -e 'select count(*) from mydb.mydb' -s)
echo $ROW_CNT
```

Also, the semicolon at end your SQL command is unnecessary

Comment: For Psql , I needed the -t option, eg ROW_CNT=$(psql -h AHOST -p APORT -d ADB -t -c 'select count( * ) from ATABLE   ;')

Answer (score 1):

try out this-

```
count=$( $path/to/mysql -h $ip -u $user -p$password $schema -s \
          -e "select count(1) from employee where email=xyz@abc.com");

if [[ "${count}" = '0' ]]; then
    break
else
    echo "Email exist, please enter a new value : "
fi
```

Comment: Please explain what your code fragment does and how this answers the question!